# double autoincrement in table mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables `Order` and `User`.

Order

```
id - pk, autoincrement
agent_id - int(contains user.id)
...
```

User

```
id - pk, autoincrement
...
```

In my project backend i use order numbering by id (e.g `1234`, `1435`, `1436`...), but at frontend user want to have unique order number (e.g `1`,`2`,`4`,`5`...),

I need for each `agent_id` unique order number. But i don't understand how to do this.

Comment: each auto increment is contained to itself, so, each of your ID fields if set to auto increment will start at either 0 or 1, (forget which I think its 1) and the next will be 2, then 3 then 4.. so order can have 1,2,3,4.. and so can user id be 1,2,3,4..

Comment: Thank you for answer. But you maybe don`t understand me. In your answer, i must to create table for each agent and add autoincrement id. But it`s not correct. 
In 1 table we can have 1 autoincrement field.